# Android : setVisibility not work

Tags: android, class

I want change view `linearlayout` from class

But not work this code

> main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ComNet.readDb();
    }
}
```

And :

> ComNet.java

```
public class ComNet {
    public static Context context;

    public static void readDb() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewMain = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        LinearLayout lnrPart = (LinearLayout) viewMain.findViewById(R.id.lnrPart);
        lnrPart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

How change `lnrPart` from `main.xml` in class ( `ComNet` ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the activities rootView to readDB function.

main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ComNet.readDb(findViewById(R.id.main));
    }
}
```

ComNet.java

```
public static void readDb(View viewMain) {

    LinearLayout lnrPart = (LinearLayout) viewMain.findViewById(R.id.lnrPart);
    viewMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , But this line wrong : android.R.layout.main , Error : main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: fixed the code... just erase the android. before R.layout.main

Answer (score 3):

```
 View viewMain = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

with this line you are creating a new `View`, with the content of `main.xml`. This object is different from the one you are seeing at screen in your `MainActivity`. `setVisibility` is working. You are calling it on the wrong instance